# obtener los valores pares e impares de una lista en python

Tags: python, lista

Quisiera obtener los valores pares e impares de una lista de enteros en Python. He intentado lo siguiente:

```
lista_1 = [1, 5, 7, 13, 22, 15, 26, 64, 34, 72, 52, 14]
obj = [f"{i} is Even" if i%2==0 else f"{i} is odd" for i  in range(0,72)]
print(len(lista_1))`
```

Comment: Cuál es el error?

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes! Y bien, ¿cuál es tu pregunta? ¿Qué problema tienes con el código que compartes? Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes. Recuerd que puedes [Editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/402137/edit) la pregunta usando el enlace bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas.

Comment: @CandidMoe hay que dejarlos crear su pregunta. COn todo y tu edición, sigue sin contarnos cuál es la pregunta. Sólo hay un enunciado

Comment: ¿Cual es el resultado esperado? ¿Qué debe imprimir?

Comment: @Alfabravo. Esta bien confusa la cosa. Tiene una lista, pero luego crea un objeto sin usar esa lista. Finalmente imprime el largo de la lista. Nunca examina la lista, nunca imprime un "odd" o "even".

Answer (score 1):

Tu código únicamente imprime la longitud de la lista usando len() lo cual es incorrecto,

```
print(len(lista_1))
```

tienes que iterar sobre los valores del array `lista_1` (no en un rango de valores `range(0,72)` ) y determinar si cada valor es par o impar.

```
lista_1 = [1, 5, 7, 13, 22, 15, 26, 64, 34, 72, 52, 14]
#itera sobre la lista.
obj = [f"{i} is Even" if i%2==0 else f"{i} is odd" for i  in lista_1]
#imprime valores.
print(obj)
```

obtendrías como salida:

```
['1 is odd', '5 is odd', '7 is odd', '13 is odd', '22 is Even', '15 is odd', '26 is Even', '64 is Even', '34 is Even', '72 is Even', '52 is Even', '14 is Even']
```

esta es otra forma para que entiendas lo que se realiza:

```
#itera sobre la lista
for num in lista_1:
    if (num % 2) == 0:  
        print("{0} is Even".format(num))  
    else:  
        print("{0} is odd".format(num))
```

obtendrías como salida:

```
1 is odd
5 is odd
7 is odd
13 is odd
22 is Even
15 is odd
26 is Even
64 is Even
34 is Even
72 is Even
52 is Even
14 is Even
```

Answer (score 0):

Elemento de lista

o puede ser así también:

```
lista_1 = [1, 5, 7, 13, 22, 15, 26, 64, 34, 72, 52, 14]

for i in lista_1:
    if i%2==0:
        print(f"even:{i}")
    else:
        print(f"odd:{i}")
```